# AS3 Array Object Filtering Question

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object

I have an array of objects. What I would like to do is get the last index of an object whose property equals a certain value.

Ex:

```
// this occurs on a mouse click
var stockObj:Object = new Object();
stockObj.ID = "an_id";
stockObj.category = "a_category";
array.push(stockObj);
//psuedo
trace(array.lastIndexOf(stockObj.category=="a_category"));
```

I would like this to trace the index of the object whose `category` property equals `"a_category"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function searchCategory(arr:Array, cat:String):int {
    for (var i:int = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i].category == cat) {   // assuming array objects contains category
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;    // no match
}
```

Answer (score 0):

last index of searches on a string not an array: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#lastIndexOf%28%29

what you will need to do is run through the Array which will take O(n) time and compare to see which at which index has the object with category name "a_category"

```
for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){

if(array[i].category = "a_category")
maxIndex = i;
}

}
```

There is actually a better way to loop through all obj in an array of obj, but I can't remember it atm hopefully someone can comment that in but I think its something like
for (x in array){
...
}

anyways using that logic, it would be a lot faster if you reverse it, so you start at the end of the array and return the index with the first occurrence of the obj with category "a_category"